# Which CNI plugins are supported

Tags: azure-aks

Few questions in this regard.

First, which CNI plugins are officially supported in Azure. As far as I understand kubenet and azure-cni can be used, as they are options in AKS/acs-engine. Is this a correct statement?

Second - which CNIs can be used, like calico, flannel etc. Which can be safely used, and which cannot be used safely.

Answer (score 0):

At the moment [azure-cni](https://github.com/Azure/azure-container-networking/blob/master/docs/cni.md) and kubenet are the only officially supported CNIs. However, [acs-engine](https://github.com/Azure/acs-engine) [supports wider variety of CNI plugins](https://github.com/Azure/AKS/issues/589), but they are not for Azure